# Hide can't works with Subsurfed Object

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I'm using blender3.12 and faced this trouble.

In Edit mode,I can't Hide Subsurfed Mesh.

When I try to hide,there is no effort in display but Hidden Mesh can't select properly.
Some other Object and Blender2.79 Works normally with Same Project file.

Reinstall the Blender has no effort.

Is there any idea?Please Help!

[image: When Subsurf Modifier applied,Hidden Mesh appears.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Confirmed High priority bug since subdivision has been fully switched to gpu computing, see [T96080](https://developer.blender.org/T96080).

In the meantime, You can turn off GPU subdivision in the preferences: Edit → Preferences → Viewport → Subdivision → GPU Subdivision

[image]

But be aware that disabling GPU subdivision might hurt your viewport performances, up to a drastic point depending what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!!!!